# How do I configure PyCharm's Coverage checker to recognize .coveragerc?

Tags: python, pycharm, coverage.py

I have a `.coveragerc` file in the root of my project. It tells coverage.py to omit my project's migrations directories:

```
[run]
omit = *migrations*
```

When I run `coverage.py` at the command line, the config I put in .coveragerc is obeyed.

However, PyCharm does not recognize it. Is there a setting that I'm missing?

If it turns out there's no way for PyCharm to recognize `.coveragerc`, I'd be happy with even just a way to omit those directories.

Comment: Put `.coveragerc` at the root of the `tests` directory worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a feature request for this at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16945

Comment: This is now implemented, see @Jorge Leitao's answer

Answer (score 14):

You can make PyCharm use the `.coveragerc` by putting it into the working directory you run your tests from.

The feature request from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16945 was implemented and works in version 2018.1.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. 
There is also a short how to video [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tips/speed-up-coverage/)

Comment: What's the default working directory?

Answer (score 6):

There is a different way to make PyCharm ignore certain files and folders:

In the `Settings` choose `Project: ...` - `Project Structure`. Here you can mark folders as `Excluded` or exclude files specifically.

PyCharm`s code coverage reports ignores all those exluded files, too.

Comment: Does not work for me, my virtual environment folder is marked as excluded, but the generated HTML report still includes all site package files

Answer (score 3):

I found myself in the situation where I needed this badly. My travis run were running correctly and so did coveralls but I was unable to get things work in PyCharm.

The thing is a bit hacky, but hopefully it will help people :

In my root project directory, I got a .coveragerc

```
[run]
omit = ./venv
concurrency = multiprocessing
parallel = True
source = HookTest
data_file = .cache/.coverage
```

And I "hacked" a little run_coverage.py of PyCharm : (pycharm-2016.3.2/helpers/coverage_runner/run_coverage.py )

Starting at

```
argv = []
```

Replace everything with :

```
argv = []
for arg in sys.argv:
    if arg.startswith('-m') and arg[2:]:
        argv.append(arg[2:])
    else:
        argv.append(arg)

cwd = os.getcwd()

rcfile = cwd + "/.coveragerc"
if os.path.exists(rcfile):
    print("Loading rcfile")
    i = argv.index("run")+1
    argv = argv[:i] + ["--rcfile={}".format(rcfile)] + argv[i:]

sys.argv = argv

try:
    main()
finally:
    if run_cov:
        os.chdir(cwd)
        if os.getenv('COVERAGE_COMBINE'):
            main(["combine"])
        main(["xml", "-o", coverage_file + ".xml", "--ignore-errors"])
```

To make this run with python setup.py test, I created a script in PyCharm that uses said setup.py, had test has parameter, and COVERAGE_COMBINE as global env. It might not be the best of all time solutions but at least it allows me not to use HTML output anymore while working locally :)

Answer (score 1):

It does not work in the last Pycharm version 2018.3.4.
The only way I succeeded to make it works is to heck the `run_coverage.py` as @PonteIneptique

Here is the only modification I had to do:

```py
run_xml = os.getenv('PYCHARM_RUN_COVERAGE_XML')
argv = ["xml", "-o", coverage_file + ".xml", "--ignore-errors"]
rcfile = cwd + "/.coveragerc"
if os.path.exists(rcfile):
    print("Loading rcfile\n")
    argv += ["--rcfile", rcfile]


if run_xml:
    os.chdir(cwd)
    main(argv)
else:
    try:
        main()
    finally:
        if run_cov:
            os.chdir(cwd)
            main(argv)
```

Be sure to set the working dir of of the .coveragerc file too in your configuration.
Pycharm coders should update their code for supporting this .coveragerc file from the GUI.