# How to have pycharm recognizing .coveragerc file?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest-cov

This question is not a duplicate of [How do I configure PyCharm's Coverage checker to recognize .coveragerc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273364/how-do-i-configure-pycharms-coverage-checker-to-recognize-coveragerc) that is very old.

I have a project with a `.coveragerc` located at the root:

```
[run]
omit =
    **/build/**
exclude_lines =
    @abstractmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    pragma: no cover
```

I have configured the test suite like this:

[image: Pycharm pytest configuration]

However, in the PyCharm coverage window, I still get "0% files, not covered in build".

If I run pytest in the console, the coverage report generated is correct.

I have tried to put the `.coveragerc` file in the tests folder without better results.

Have you any idea what I should do differently here?

Thank you.